# How to count number of rows with NA on each column?

Tags: r

I have a dataset with more than 100 columns. How can I get a table which counts number of NAs on each column of the dataset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use the vectorized `colSums` on a logical matrix (`is.na(df1)`)

```
colSums(is.na(df1))
```

Or another option is `sum` by looping

```
sapply(df1, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    summarise(across(everything(), ~ sum(is.na(.))))
```